# How to create aws code pipelines using aws sdk boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, github, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-codepipeline

I want to create a CI/CD pipeline using python with github as source stage and aws s3 bucket as deploy stage. I am not able to understand how to use the functions given at https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codepipeline.html and it does not have sample code too.
I also came across AWS CDK. which do I use and where can I find sample code to get started?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a lot of examples for AWS boto3 python, one of them show how to create aws codepipline with github as source control: [this](https://github.com/hms-dbmi/aws-python-utilities)